# Galois group of $X^{2p}+1-tX^p \in \mathbb{F}_p(t)[X]$,$\,$ $p>2$ is prime

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to find the Galois group of these polynomials:

(1) $X^4-2X^3-8X-3\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$

(2) $X^{2p}+1-tX^p \in \mathbb{F}_p(t)[X]$, where $p>2$ is prime

For (1), I have shown that its Galois group is either $A_3$ or $S_3$, and since $X^4-2X^3-8X-3=(X^3+X^2+3X+1)(X-3)$ and $X^3+X^2+3X+1$ has exactly one real root, its Galois group contains a transposition, and I'm done.

I'm quite stuck on (2). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The polynomial in (2) not separable. Over the extension field $\Bbb{F}_p(t^{1/p})$ it factors as $(X^2-t^{1/p}X+1)^p$. You only get the automorphisms of the splitting field of that quadratic over $\Bbb{F}_p(t^{1/p})$